# Javascript Timer with setInterval not working?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, setinterval

I have a Timer that is being drawn, but not changing at all. It shows 0: 01, and is not adding by the second. This probably has something to do with the setInterval, but i am not sure.

```
function drawTimer() {
    var fontSize = 15;
    graph.lineWidth = playerConfig.textBorderSize;
    graph.fillStyle = playerConfig.textColor;
    graph.strokeStyle = playerConfig.textBorder;
    graph.miterLimit = 1;
    graph.lineJoin = 'round';
    graph.textAlign = 'right';
    graph.textBaseline = 'middle';
    graph.font = 'bold ' + fontSize + 'px sans-serif';

    var gameTimeMinutes = 0;
    var gameTimeSeconds = 1;
    var gameTime = "";

    function addTime() {
        gameTimeSeconds += 1;
    }

setInterval(addTime, 1000);

if (gameTimeSeconds < 10) {
    gameTime = gameTimeMinutes + " : 0" + gameTimeSeconds;
} else {
    gameTime = gameTimeMinutes + " : " + gameTimeSeconds;
}

if (gameTimeSeconds == 60) {
    gameTimeSeconds = 0;
    gameTimeMinutes++;
}

    graph.strokeText(gameTime, 50, 50);
    graph.fillText(gameTime, 50, 50);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please create snippet or fiddle!!! so we can understand

Comment: All you are doing every 1000ms is adding 1 to a variable.  You’re not redrawing anything.  You would need to add your drawing code to the addTime function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval(addTime, 1000)` calls `addTime` every second but nothing appears to happen because the timer is not being redrawn. You could redraw the timer by calling `drawTimer`, but all the timer data is inside the `drawTimer` function.

Calling `drawTimer` multiple times doesn't help either because all the values are being reseted on each call. You can solve this by using global variables and functions to manage the timer state (`gameTimeMinutes`, `gameTimeSeconds` and `gameTime`), but you probably want to use ***objects*** for this. You can read more about objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

In this example a `GameTimer` object is created. The `GameTimer` is defined by a function, it doesn't do anything until an object is created using the `new` keyword. Then you can `addTime` or `draw` by calling those functions on the object `gameTimer.addTime()`, `gameTimer.draw()`. Alternatively you can do both with the `update` function which is what happens with `setInterval`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var graph = canvas.getContext("2d");
var playerConfig = {
  textBorderSize: 3,
  textColor: "white",
  textBorder: "black"
}

function GameTimer() {
  var gameTimeMinutes = 0;
  var gameTimeSeconds = 0;
  var gameTime = "";
  
  this.addTime = function() {
    gameTimeSeconds += 1;
    if (gameTimeSeconds < 10) {
        gameTime = gameTimeMinutes + " : 0" + gameTimeSeconds;
    } else {
        gameTime = gameTimeMinutes + " : " + gameTimeSeconds;
    }

    if (gameTimeSeconds == 60) {
        gameTimeSeconds = 0;
        gameTimeMinutes++;
    }
  };
  
  this.draw = function() {
    graph.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var fontSize = 15;
    graph.lineWidth = playerConfig.textBorderSize;
    graph.fillStyle = playerConfig.textColor;
    graph.strokeStyle = playerConfig.textBorder;
    graph.miterLimit = 1;
    graph.lineJoin = 'round';
    graph.textAlign = 'right';
    graph.textBaseline = 'middle';
    graph.font = 'bold ' + fontSize + 'px sans-serif';
    graph.strokeText(gameTime, 60, 50);
    graph.fillText(gameTime, 60, 50);
  };
  
  this.update = function() {
    this.addTime();
    this.draw();
  }.bind(this);
  
  this.update();
}

var gameTimer = new GameTimer();
setInterval(gameTimer.update, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Fantastic! But one problem, every time the time updates,  it blinks, making it almost ineligible. How can i remove that blinking and make a switch switch to the next time?

Comment: I meant smooth switch in my previous comment*

Comment: I can't notice the blinking, although I think `graph.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` might be causing the issue. It's a function that clears the canvas so that might explain the blinks. Maybe you could replace it with the [fillRect function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) and just fill over the numbers.

Comment: Hmm, its still blinking. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tested it and if i speed up the interval then it blinks faster, which means that every time the interval plays, the text appears and then disappears, instead of appears until the next one plays. how can i make it appear until the next one plays/

Answer (score 0):

The `addTime()` is being called every 1 second, but looks like the code bellow the line with `setInterval(addTime, 1000);` is only being executed once. That being said, you variable `gameTime` is only being set once. You should reevaluate your logic to include these changes(update, and print) on your interval.

Comment: Does that mean that i should set the interval another place in the code? Can you give me an example on how i can make it get executed multiple times?